# Considering the universe has a limited timespan, how would god fit into this?

Tags: metaphysics, theology, existence, universe

Let's consider the universe to have an existence that is temporally limited (i.e., it will eventually implodes on itself or falls apart). Now, let's consider that there is a god in that universe.

What would the god do?  Would he sit there with nothing to do forever or he would seize to exist if universe would fall apart, or be reborn anew if universe would go into another cycle or some other option?

Comment: This is not going to be answerable in a sensible way.

Comment: This has been asked already by our common friend Albert (Einstein), Albert said - "I want to know what god **thinks** **?** ". So your question can be generalized and put like this - "What is god doing **right** now?" It is super fundamental and important question. I hope he is not stuck in some sort of forum.

Comment: What's your definition of "god"?

Comment: "Would he sit there with nothing to do forever ..." Yes, and one day he gets bored and says, "Let there be light." This is not only one of humanity's oldest myths; it's also the punchline of an Isaac Asimov story. Not exactly news.

Comment: @AsphirDom "I hope he is not stuck in some sort of forum". I lol'd

Comment: @Gerald guy from the bible in this case, not something outside of the universe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A physical god, not a metaphysical one, would be subject to the laws of physics, and could therefore only exist in space-time (space plus time). Space-time is bound to the universe according to [current cosmological models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model).

Based on our limited current knowledge, the universe will expand forever, and changes will slow down over very long timescales ("[heat death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe)").

Hence a physical god of whatever properties in detail would gradually cease to exist in the sense of being a distinguishable and active individual; that's roughly equivalent to sitting there and doing gradually less and less, and ending up in perfect randomness without goal or direction. This is not just because of possible asymptotically and locally reaching maximum entropy, but also by thinning due to [exponential expansion of the universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerating_universe).

At the end, there is nothing else than expanding vacuum with [random fluctuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation) near absoute zero temperature.

Or using the "god" metaphor: A physical god is sitting there, and is bored, forever.

Outside our space-time, beyond physical infinity, other space-times may (metaphysically) exist, with other life-forms pondering about their universe and beyond.

In a [many-worlds multiverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) space-times can be related to each other, although without physical communication between them, in a way that one could define something like a common time for at least some of the universes. In this scenario, the existence of a god in one universe would imply an infinite number of similar, but not quite identical god-twins, at most one per parallel universe.
This could also be interpreted as an infinite sequence of infinite periods of time, infinitely many, although not necessarily all of the items of the infinite sequence, causing a rebirth of a presumed god, each one with a similar, but not necessarily identical fate.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding current cosmological theories about finite universe. Even if it were true that the Universe has finite time to exist (which is not true), it would not cease to exist physically. What is meant by the collapse is that something else would happen, but we do not currently know what, based on the physical laws we know now. So, to answer your question, NO - if there is a god, whether a material or immaterial being, she would not notice or care. 
EDIT: -- hmm, this is a dumb answer, actually, what I meant is that the god would not be destroyed.